# .htaccess and rewrite sub domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a website that runs on a custom framework. However i would like to add a gateway subdomain to handle specific requests. As well as a api subdomain to handle api requests.

Now is have a complex folder structure:

```
-application
-config
-subs (subdomain folder)
  - gateway
  - api
-library
-public
  .htaccess [2]
-scripts
-tmp
.htaccess [1]
```

Now i would like to get the http://gateway.example.com to redirect to subs > gateway and the http://api.example.com to subs > api folders.

The first .htaccess [1]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/scripts/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

The second .htaccess [2] (i don't think this needed to post here, but you newer know ;)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^popup/   - [L]
RewriteRule ^img/   - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              index.php?url=$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

I think i should change the first .htaccess [1]. But to what?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by setting up your `VirtulDomain` correctly like this for `gateway` sub domain:

```
DocumentRoot /home/example/domains/example.com/public_html/subs/gateway
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, thanks for your quick reply. But i'm still getting an Internal Server Error, when requesting: http://gateway.example.com/test.html

Comment: I had a mistake, just fixed. Can you try now.

Comment: For some reason it is not working. Still internal server error. Main site (in public) is still working.

Comment: 1 step further, now it provides us with aan Not Found. But actually there is a file named: test.html in the gateway folder. Requesting the url: http://gateway.example.com/test.html provides me with a not found.

Comment: Well then you you wrote that `http://gateway.example.com to redirect to subs > gateway` You need to make sure first that your original target URI is working fine. Are you sure `gateway.example.com` is same `DocumentRoot` as `www.example.com`?

Comment: Sorry, that isn't working either. See folder structure here: http://i42.tinypic.com/34ihbup.png or in FTP console http://i43.tinypic.com/al6984.png

Comment: Nope, internal server Error

Comment: can you check your Apache error.log for the reason of this error?

Comment: Nothing the see there.. But in the usage log there is a request. 212.78.198.20 - - [15/Jan/2014:20:54:49 +0100] "GET /subs/gateway/test.html HTTP/1.1" 200 362 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.73.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.1 Safari/537.73.11"

Comment: Well this is showing `200` status which is not internal error.

Comment: Just checked. that is the request to www.example.com/subs/gateway/test.html. That was working when I moved the sub folder to the public directory

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45314/discussion-between-peter-fox-and-anubhava)