# .htaccess rewrite rule with DocumentRoot subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to implement some htaccess rewrite rules. However in not a pro in htaccess.

I have a subdomain gateway in (as described in: [.htaccess and rewrite sub domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146098/htaccess-and-rewrite-sub-domains))

Now i would like to use SEO friendly URL's. The gateway has some subfolders i.e. email in this case.

http://gateway.example.com/email/Param1/Param2/

This url should be rewritten to http://gateway.example.com/email/index.php?hash=Param1&hash2=Param2.

In the email folder I have created a .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?hash=$1&hash2=$2
```

When requesting the http://gateway.example.com/email/Param1/Param2/ i'm now getting a 404. What is wrong with the rule?

Comment: ok so does going to http://gateway.example.com work as intended first off? and what is your document root for it?

Comment: @PanamaJack yes it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it this way

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ /email/index.php?hash=$1&hash2=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/ index.php?hash=$1&hash2=$2
```

*you need to configure apache(httpd) to accept UrlRewrite by changing  AllowOverride from non to all  like this :

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride all
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: did you allow .htaccess on your apache server ?

Comment: *you need to configure apache(httpd) to accept UrlRewrite by changing  AllowOverride from non to all  like this (on /etc/httpd/config/httpd.conf for centos):

<Directory "/var/www/html">
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride all
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</Directory>